# Why is there no sound when "code complex" but there are sound when "code simple"?

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code, p5.js

I'm using p5.js for vscode and can't hear any sound in "html live server" but editor.p5js.org is working just fine

Website before change > **Calculating Digits of Pi with Collisions p5.js
https://editor.p5js.org/Josef37/sketches/RGDv9lHkK**

I only change the image name and the sound name but use **gong file read only**

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Sketch</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    <script src="libraries/p5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libraries/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libraries/quicksettings.js"></script>
    <script src="libraries/p5.gui.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script src="(P5.jsEditor)PiCollisionsBlock.js"></script>
    <script src="(P5.jsEditor)PiCollisionsSketch.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**(P5.jsEditor)PiCollisionsSketch.js**

```js
// Pi Day Collisions
// Josef Wittmann
// https://thecodingtrain.com/CodingChallenges/139-pi-collisions.html
// https://youtu.be/PoW8g67XNxA
// In all demos the computations only considered the beginning or the end of one frame. 
// This may work well for games, but it can get incorrect numerically pretty fast.
// (I was wondering that results stayed accurate, even if the squared overlapped by 1% of the big one for 7 digits) 
// This simulation wanted to preserve the aspect of a simulation, while considering collisions within one frame 
// instead of bumping up the computational steps within one frame or resetting positions. 
// The improvement shows a more realistic result and faster computation when there is a moderate amount of collisions.

let blockImg;
let block1;
let block2;
let Gong;//Change
// How much time passes within ones frame
const frameTime = 2;
// You have to remember, if the last collision was with the other block or a wall, 
// because the blocks can start to overlap in the size of machine epsilon and you would expect the wrong collision next
let isNextCollisionWithBlock = true;

let count = 0;
let digits = 5;
let countDiv;

function preload() {
  blockImg = loadImage('PiCollisionsBlock.png');//Change
  Gong = loadSound('Gong.wav');//Change
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, 200);
  block1 = new Block(100, 20, 1, 0, 0);
  const m2 = pow(100, digits - 1);
  block2 = new Block(300, 100, m2, -1, 20);
  countDiv = createDiv(count);
  countDiv.style('font-size', '48pt');
}

function draw() {
  background(200);

  let GongSound = false;//Change
  let remainingFrameTime = frameTime;
  let doneStr = "";

  // Repeat as long as something collides in this frame
  while (true) {
    let timeToCollision = isNextCollisionWithBlock ?
      block1.timeToBlockCollision(block2) :
      block1.timeToWallCollision();
      
    // There will be no more collision at all
    if (timeToCollision < 0) {
      doneStr = "Done! ";
      break;
    }
    // No more collision in this frame
    if (remainingFrameTime <= timeToCollision) {
      break;
    }

    block1.move(timeToCollision);
    block2.move(timeToCollision);

    // Block collision
    if (isNextCollisionWithBlock) {
      const v1 = block1.bounce(block2);
      const v2 = block2.bounce(block1);
      block1.v = v1;
      block2.v = v2;
      GongSound = true;//Change
      count++;
    } // Wall collision
    else {
      block1.reverse();
      GongSound = true;//Change
      count++;
    }

    // Update after collision
    isNextCollisionWithBlock = !isNextCollisionWithBlock;
    remainingFrameTime -= timeToCollision;
  }

  // Move the rest of the frame
  block1.move(remainingFrameTime);
  block2.move(remainingFrameTime);


  if (GongSound) {//Change
    Gong.play();//Change
  }
  block1.show();
  block2.show();

  countDiv.html(doneStr + nf(count, digits));
}
```

**(P5.jsEditor)PiCollisionsBlock.js**

```js
class Block {
    constructor(x, w, m, v, xc) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = height - w;
      this.w = w;
      this.v = v;
      this.m = m;
      this.xConstraint = xc;
    }
  
    timeToWallCollision() {
        return - this.x / this.v;
    }
    
    // this is left, other is right
    timeToBlockCollision(other) {
        let deltaX = other.x - (this.x + this.w);
        let deltaV = this.v - other.v;
        return deltaX / deltaV;
    }
  
    reverse() {
      this.v *= -1;
    }
  
    bounce(other) {
      let sumM = this.m + other.m;
      let newV = (this.m - other.m) / sumM * this.v;
      newV += (2 * other.m / sumM) * other.v;
      return newV;
    }
  
    move(deltaTime) {
      this.x += this.v * deltaTime;
    }
  
    show() {
      image(blockImg, this.x, this.y, this.w, this.w);
    }
  }
```

I do the simple code and it work just fine the only error in console is "Cannot GET /libraries/p5.sound.min.js.map" which is not that much consider the "simple code sound work" just fine

the simple code "TestSong.js"

**TestSong.js**

```js
let song;

function setup() {
  song = loadSound('gong.wav');
  createCanvas(720, 200);
  background(255, 0, 0);
}

function mousePressed() {
  if (song.isPlaying()) {
    // .isPlaying() returns a boolean
    song.stop();
    background(255, 0, 0);
  } else {
    song.play();
    background(0, 255, 0);
  }
}

/*
https://p5js.org/examples/sound-load-and-play-sound.html
*/
```

Comment: Im not sure what is is you're actually asking, but it sounds like you don't have the sound library installed locally.

Answer (score 0):

lol I just debug today by adding how many change i use //1234, in https://editor.p5js.org/Josef37/sketches/RGDv9lHkK and vscode, then i live server and it work... 1/10 time, when i retry the browser and vscode it did not work, i thought of too much ram so i quit all other browser... did not work... only 1/10 time work, so I guess that it work but... due to using safari and old MacBook air and/or no http server that the sound take so long to load and fail to read the sound file

```js
// Pi Day Collisions
// Josef Wittmann
// https://thecodingtrain.com/CodingChallenges/139-pi-collisions.html
// https://youtu.be/PoW8g67XNxA
// In all demos the computations only considered the beginning or the end of one frame. 
// This may work well for games, but it can get incorrect numerically pretty fast.
// (I was wondering that results stayed accurate, even if the squared overlapped by 1% of the big one for 7 digits) 
// This simulation wanted to preserve the aspect of a simulation, while considering collisions within one frame 
// instead of bumping up the computational steps within one frame or resetting positions. 
// The improvement shows a more realistic result and faster computation when there is a moderate amount of collisions.

let blockImg;
let block1;
let block2;
let Gong;//Change1
// How much time passes within ones frame
const frameTime = 2;
// You have to remember, if the last collision was with the other block or a wall, 
// because the blocks can start to overlap in the size of machine epsilon and you would expect the wrong collision next
let isNextCollisionWithBlock = true;

let count = 0;
let digits = 5;
let countDiv;

function preload() {
  blockImg = loadImage('PiCollisionsBlock.png');//Change2
  Gong = loadSound('Gong.wav');//Change34
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, 200);
  block1 = new Block(100, 20, 1, 0, 0);
  const m2 = pow(100, digits - 1);
  block2 = new Block(300, 100, m2, -1, 20);
  countDiv = createDiv(count);
  countDiv.style('font-size', '48pt');
}

function draw() {
  background(200);

  let GongSound = false;//Change5
  let remainingFrameTime = frameTime;
  let doneStr = "";

  // Repeat as long as something collides in this frame
  while (true) {
    let timeToCollision = isNextCollisionWithBlock ?
      block1.timeToBlockCollision(block2) :
      block1.timeToWallCollision();
      
    // There will be no more collision at all
    if (timeToCollision < 0) {
      doneStr = "Done! ";
      break;
    }
    // No more collision in this frame
    if (remainingFrameTime <= timeToCollision) {
      break;
    }

    block1.move(timeToCollision);
    block2.move(timeToCollision);

    // Block collision
    if (isNextCollisionWithBlock) {
      const v1 = block1.bounce(block2);
      const v2 = block2.bounce(block1);
      block1.v = v1;
      block2.v = v2;
      GongSound = true;//Change6
      count++;
    } // Wall collision
    else {
      block1.reverse();
      GongSound = true;//Change7
      count++;
    }

    // Update after collision
    isNextCollisionWithBlock = !isNextCollisionWithBlock;
    remainingFrameTime -= timeToCollision;
  }

  // Move the rest of the frame
  block1.move(remainingFrameTime);
  block2.move(remainingFrameTime);


  if (GongSound) {//Change8
    Gong.play();//Change9
  }
  block1.show();
  block2.show();

  countDiv.html(doneStr + nf(count, digits));
}
```